# Cannot finish first backup with Time Machine

Tags: time-machine

My first Time Machine backup systematically fails when it is about to finish.

I looked at the system logs and I have these errors:

```
Failed to unmount '/Volumes/Copies de sauvegarde Time Machine' (disk2s2), dissenter: {
    DAProcessID = 263;
    DAStatus = 49168;
} with status: 49168 (null)

Failed to eject 'disk2' using DiskArb, dissenter: {
    DAStatus = 49168;
} with status: 49168 (null)

Failed to eject 'disk2' (using ioctl), error: 16 Resource busy

Failed to remove directory '/Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.TimeMachineFolder-28BD73CD-4059-43D4-B1BE-0CA9C98D5EFD', error: 16 Resource busy
```

I have macOS 10.14.6 (18G103)

Any idea of the problem?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, after having seen similar several times, two things to try; one free, the other paid.

First clear down any stray local backups, from Terminal.

`tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` will list them.
`tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 1000000000000 1` will pretty aggressively cull them.

List again afterwards & make sure only one or two remain, & that none of them are tagged `dataless`.

Try running Time Machine again.

If still no joy, then the only way I've ever found to fix this is to run [DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) on the Time Machine drive. Apple's Disk Utility never seems to work.
Fortunately, TM drives *must* be HFS+, as Disk Warrior cannot yet handle APFS.